# Why I got tornado.autoreload started more than once in testing?

Tags: python, tornado

I use *tornado.testing* to implement my tornado handlers' unit test. The tests seems to be working. But I got below error for every test function.

```
[W 141027 19:13:25 autoreload:117] tornado.autoreload started more than once in the same process
```

Does it matters? How can I stop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't hurt anything, but the warning means you are probably passing `debug=True` to each Application you create in your tests. You probably don't want to use debug mode in tests (and if you do you can pass `autoreload=False` to turn this off, or use some of the other options to only turn on the parts of debug mode that you need.